# Using properties to modify model field Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I Have model fields as illustrated below:-

```
user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True)
_corporate = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, db_column='corporate')
def set_corporate(self,value):
    if self.user.corporateuser_set.all():
        self._corporate = self.user.corporateuser_set.values_list('company', flat=True)
corporate= property(set_corporate)
```

Somehow, set_corporate is not being evaluated and therefore _corporate field is not updated.

So what should I do to make it work? what's the best approach here?

I have another model(CorporateUser) with a one to many relationship with User Model, just to clarity of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are doing it wrong in so many ways.

First, properties are used this way in python:

```
class A:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value
```

Or this way:

```
class A:
    def get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    def set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

    foo = property(get_foo, set_foo)
```

Note how value is passed to setter. It should not be computed there as you do. If you need to autoupdate corporate value then you don't need a property, you should overwrite models `.save()` method or listen to its `pre_save` signal and update field there.

Second, you should not conditionally set in setter. Setter should always set property to value passed. Like this:

```
def set_corporate(self, value):
    # If the list is empty then corporate becomes empty
    self._corporate = \
        self.user.corporateuser_set.values_list('company', flat=True)
```

By violating this rule you will cause grief:

```
obj.corporate = 'hi'
# obj.corporate is now 'hi'
obj.corporate = ''
# obj.corporate is still 'hi'. WTF?
```

Third, you should not assign `list` to `CharField`. How this supposed to work? It will probably stringify it.

Forth, you are not even assigning a list, you are assigning queryset, which is worse.

Fifth, you are doing essentially same database request twice in a two lines. The efficient way to check if that is empty and then assign is by reusing same queryset:

```
corporates = self.user.corporateuser_set.values_list('company', flat=True)
if corporates:
    # Stringify it explicitly and our way
    self._corporate = ','.join(corporates)
```

Comment: 'By violating this rule you will cause grief:' what
 rule?

Comment: Setter should set unconditionally.

Comment: For your explanation, am accepting your answer. Its well detailed, but I will disagree with the option of using save(). I think the best way is to use the property virtual field. It seems to work well for now, not sure if it's effieciency will last though :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use properties. The first argument to the [`property` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), if you use it like that, is the *getter* method. You haven't even provided a getter method. You need one which returns the value of `self._corporate`.

Comment: I added the getter method as `def get_corporate(self):
        if self._corporate:
            return self._corporate` Then I edited my property function to `corporate = property(get_corporate, set_corporate)` But even with that it did niot work! Am I missing something still?